# When do Rust editions, such as 2015, reach end of life?

Tags: rust

Rust has different editions. The oldest edition is [Rust 2015](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2015/index.html). The current version is [Rust 2018](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/edition-guide/rust-2018/index.html). There is a planned release for [Rust 2021](https://blog.rust-lang.org/inside-rust/2021/03/04/planning-rust-2021.html). When will Rust 2015 be end of life and unsupported by `rustc`?

Comment: related: https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/possible-lts-releases-tied-to-editions/7380/23

Comment: The official docs claim they'll all keep getting updates https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/editions/index.html --  `Just to be clear: most features will be available on all editions. People using any edition of Rust will continue to see improvements as new stable releases are made.`

Comment: @Gus This looks like a valid answer, not just a comment

Answer (score 5):

The official [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/editions/index.html) claim official editions will keep getting updates.

> Compatibility
>
> When a new edition becomes available in the compiler,
> crates must explicitly opt in to it to take full advantage. This opt
> in enables editions to contain incompatible changes, like adding a new
> keyword that might conflict with identifiers in code, or turning
> warnings into errors. **A Rust compiler will support all editions that
> existed prior to the compiler's release, and can link crates of any
> supported editions together.** Edition changes only affect the way the
> compiler initially parses the code. Therefore, if you're using Rust
> 2015, and one of your dependencies uses Rust 2018, it all works just
> fine. The opposite situation works as well.
>
> Just to be clear: most features will be available on all editions.
> **People using any edition of Rust will continue to see improvements as
> new stable releases are made.** In some cases however, mainly when new
> keywords are added, but sometimes for other reasons, there may be new
> features that are only available in later editions. You only need to
> upgrade if you want to take advantage of such features.

(emphasis added)

Answer (score 0):

An edition of Rust is timeless, the implementation will hit EOL. This from  Programming Rust Second Edition,

> Any code that compiled on Rust 1.0 must compile just as well on Rust 1.50 or, if it's ever released, Rust 1.900. [...] Rust promises that the compiler will accept all **extant** editions of the language, and programs can freely mix creates written in different editions.

So basically rustc is under semvar*. When an edition of Rust has fallen into disuse, rustc reserves the right to drop support for that specific edition of Rust. When this happens they'll bump the major version and we'll have rustc version 2.0.

Until then assume that all editions of Rust will be supported by rustc.

---

This isn't entirely true, there are some exceptions like the one mentioned [in the blog post announcing Rust 2021](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/05/11/edition-2021.html)

> Instead, we decided to add the trait implementation in all editions (starting in Rust 1.53.0), but add a small hack to avoid breakage until Rust 2021. In Rust 2015 and 2018 code, the compiler will still resolve array.into_iter() to (&array).into_iter() like before, as if the trait implementation does not exist. This only applies to the `.into_iter()` method call syntax. It does not affect any other syntax such as `for e in [1, 2, 3]`, `iter.zip([1, 2, 3])` or `IntoIterator::into_iter([1, 2, 3])`. Those will start to work in all editions.

This means you **can** write code in Rust 1.53.0 for Eddition 2018 which does not work in code compiled in Rust 1.52.0. However likely that is, I'm not sure.

Comment: The quotes you cite are good; but I think your interpretation of them is not quite correct. Rust, as a project, does not "reserve the right to drop support"; rather, the backwards compatibility promise is intended specifically to prohibit this. In other words, yes, Rust follows semver ("ver" as in "version"), but there is a strong intent within the project never to release "rustc version 2.0".

I don't quite understand your Rust 2021 example. Editions are not "frozen", as new features are added, rustc will permit code that would not previously compile, but that's not a breaking change.